# How do I set the description of an Azure Pipeline Secure File?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In my Azure DevOps Pipeline Library, I added a secure file - a temporary license file - for use in testing.  After I added it, I saw that there was a "Description" field.  So I clicked the "..." button to  to edit it.  But in the page that follows, there does not appear to be any way to edit the description field.  Am I missing it?  If not, where does the description get set?

Comment: Good catch. I also didn't a way to set it via REST API nor CLI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like editting the description  of secure files is not supported in azure devops currently. See [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/671812/secure-files-description-cannot-be-set.html).

You can [submit a feature request here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) to microsoft development team. Hope they will consider supporting setting the description of secure files.